# Trouble with web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a configuration in my web.config like this?

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BASE_URL" value="/mvc/" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

in my web.Release.config, I have this:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BASE_URL" value="/mvc" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

but, when I call BASE_URL property, it's return "/mvc/" and not "/mvc"
I using the Release Configuration to build my project
I using C# MVC4 in VS 2013

Comment: You need to do a publish within Visual Studio for the transform to actually happen.

Comment: Transformations won't be applied if you hit F5, only when you publish the project.

Comment: @AndrehOdon You can install [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) extension which transforms config files during an "F5" session.